# How do I setup node-sass to combine files after they are compiled?

Tags: node.js, express, sass

I'm running a newly generated node/express app and am trying to use node-sass. How can I render my sass files and combine them into a single css file.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of code that you have completed so far would help but here goes:- Firstly you may want to add in some partials to combine some files anyway then you could do something similar to this in your grunt file or other:-

```
   options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        outputStyle: 'expanded',
        includePaths: ['sass/', 'sass/modules/']
    },
    dist: {
        files: {
            'sass/non-responsive.css' : 'sass/non-responsive.scss',
            'sass/responsive.css' : 'sass/responsive.scss'
        }
    }
```